# how to pull value from wilcoxsign test in R

Tags: r

how can i pull the z ?

[image]

**Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Pratt Signed-Rank Test**

```
data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
     stratified by block
Z = 2.5113, p-value = 0.01203
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Please provide the package from which that function comes from. Otherwise, examine the structure of the returned object using `str()`. It's likely a list object, of which one of its elements includes the Z value.

Answer (score 1):

The `wilcoxsign_test()` function is from the `coin` package (this is useful information for people answering).

**Most** R functions work the way that @ChrisRuehlemann suggests, but `wilcoxsign_test()` is an exception; it's stored as an S4 class, which makes things a little more obscure. You have to dig down with some combination of `str()` and `slotNames()`, and access individual elements via @

```
library(coin)
w <- wilcoxsign_test(mpg~vs,data=mtcars)
slotNames(w)
## [1] "parameter"    "nullvalue"    "distribution" "statistic"    
## "estimates"   
## [6] "method"       "call" 
w@statistic@teststatistic
## [1] 4.937168
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to store the test as an object and extract the value of interest from there. For example, using the `wilcox.test`:

```
test <- wilcox.test(rnorm(100), dnorm(1000))

test

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  rnorm(100) and dnorm(1000)
W = 54, p-value = 0.9044
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Just type the name of your test object, add `$`and run your cursor over it to see the options for what you can extract, for example:

```
test$statistic
 W 
54
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @BenBolker response, as soon as you find out what you want to extract, after using the `wilcoxsign_test()` function and assuming the test results are stored in `w`, you can use:

```
# Z value
statistic(w)
# p value
pvalue(w)
```